# Match last occurrence of a word before another word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking to match the last refId before jdbc/myds in the following html snippet so I'd be looking to get back 'DataSource_1478537797505'

I tried

```
(?s)refId=(.*?)&(?!refId).*jdbc\/myds
```

as in Single line mode.
Match a refId= and group everything up to the next & while negatively looking ahead for other instances of refId before encountering myds

```
<div id="nameCollectionDiv9">

    <A HREF="dataSourceCollection.do?csrfid=644853468&EditAction=true&refId=DataSource_1436886953637&contextId=cells%3AWASUAT1_Cell&resourceUri=resources.xml&perspective=tab.configuration">

<div id="jndiNameCollectionDiv9">

    jdbc/old_workflow_XA

    <A HREF="dataSourceCollection.do?csrfid=644853468&EditAction=true&refId=DataSource_1436886597868&contextId=cells%3AWASUAT1_Cell&resourceUri=resources.xml&perspective=tab.configuration">

<div id="jndiNameCollectionDiv10">

    jdbc/old_workflow

<div id="nameCollectionDiv11">

    <A HREF="dataSourceCollection.do?csrfid=644853468&EditAction=true&refId=DataSource_1478537797505&contextId=cells%3AWASUAT1_Cell&resourceUri=resources.xml&perspective=tab.configuration">

    jdbc/myds
```

Thanks
Mark.

Comment: If you want to keep it similar to the way you've currently got it, try: `refId=(.*?)(&(?!refId)|[^&])*jdbc\/myds`. I'd post this as an answer, but regex101 seems to be down for me, and I feel like I should give a working example

Comment: Thanks for the try Addison, I tried this out but to no avail. Somehow it still matches from the first redId right through the second until the jdbc/myds.. At this point I'm baffled, I can't understand why there isn't a [^[refId]]* that allows you to match whatever isn't the string refId but the [^...] only appears to be able to negative match on groups characters like all the letters in 'refId'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find more useful using a **xhtml parser** than using a regex, it is usually the right tool for that.

Anyway, if you still want to use a regex, then you can use a regex like this (no need to use lookarounds):

```
(?s).*refId=(.*?)&
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSaTlc/1)**

Comment: Wow that works?? I can't really understand why the first refId doesn't match though Federico but this work?

Comment: (?s).*refId=(.*?)&.*jdbc\/myds

for completeness in case a further Datasource was defined after the one I'm looking for

Comment: @MarkGargan the trick is that I am using `.*` this is a greedy operator, so it will much everything up to the last `refId`. You can play with greedy and lazy operator so see the difference. The lazy (or ungreedy) operator would be `.*?`